# Minimizing memory usage when passing large data between variables

Tags: java, image, memory, loading, pass-by-value

I know the question of Java being pass-by-reference or pass-by-value is beating a dead horse but I do have a question regarding memory usage.

The way I understand Java now is that:

```
public class MyInt{
    int value;
}

MyInt x;
MyInt y;
x = new MyInt(3);    // value of x is now 3
y = x;               // y now points to same object that x points to
y.setValue(1);       // value of said object is now 1
x.getValue();        // should return 1 instead of 3
```

But my question is how memory intensive is it to set this new `y`? Ex: if the value of MyInt were some very very large image instead of an integer,

```
x = new MyImage("very large image");   // eats memory depending on size of image
```

Would naturally take a lot of memory to have that image loaded if it were very large. I just want to make sure that when I call

```
    y = x; // y now points to same image that x does
```

`y` is just a reference to the object that `x` is already pointing at right? So when I call `y = x`; it would not be memory intensive no matter how large the image as long as that image had already been loaded via initializing `x`.

Is this correct? What pitfalls should I avoid to keep the same very large image from being loaded into memory multiple times?

Comment: If you are concerned that you might call `new MyImage("some string")` with the _same_ argument multiple times, and that it would create multiple copies of the same large image, then you can use a cache to avoid the problem.  A `Map` such as a `HashMap` would be a simple way of maintaining that kind of cache.

Comment: `Is this correct?` - yes, both y and x only hold the memory address of the large object. The memory address is an integer (small) on most systems.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you're right, any non primitive instance assignment to a non primitive reference variable is just reference assignment.

So if there's a memory location for x say mem1 then y=x will make y to point to mem1. Now even if x were to point to a new memory location mem2, y will still be pointing to mem1. So that's a pitfall to be avoided.

You almost will never be able to load a very large object multiple times without noticing it first, as you would either be creating new object calling the constructor or using some form of clone() method.

One pitfall unrelated to large objects but related to pass by reference in Java is that a reference variable passed to a method can not be dereferenced.

So suppose there's a method `dereferenceMe(MyInt x) {x = new MyInt();}` it won't change the actual reference of x in the caller method. As Java will pass the reference by value, meaning it creates a copy of reference variable and that copy is passed to the methods.

Comment: In your last point about dereferencing. Does that mean you now have two references of MyInt?

Comment: Yes, one in the caller method and one in the called method.

Comment: Does this work the same in other compiled languages like c#?

Comment: I don't know about C#, but from the look of it it's like C and C++, any reference is a pointer, that's different from Java.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, when you call `y=x` it would simply set `y` to refer the location of "very large image". There still would be only 1 object in memory which would be referenced by both `x` and `y`.

To avoid the very large image from loading again and again in memory, just don't create a new object with that image again. Avoid deep copy of the object as well.